# How to access Filtered data from Webdatarocks table

Tags: angular, webdatarocks

Is there way to access Filtered data from Webdatarocks table.

In webdatarocks, we can use filters to filter out the data. I need to pass this filtered data to independent graphs, so want to utilize the filtered output. Any help in this highly appreciated.

https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/fields-filtering/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your chart to filter the data simultaneously with the pivot, you need to add the `updateHandler` to your `getData` function.
Here is the example with `updateHandler` in `getData` function used to synchronize WebDataRocks pivot with Highcharts [in the docs](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/integration-with-highcharts/).